# Check whether the given function is differentiable at $(0,0)$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, proof-verification

> For the function$$f(x,y)= \begin{cases} \frac{x^2 \sin y}{x^2+y^2} &
>  \text{if}\, (x,y) \neq (0,0)\\ 0                          &
> \text{if}\,(x,y) = (0,0) \end{cases}$$
>
> 1. Show that $f$ is continuous at $(0,0)$.
> 2. Calculate $f_x(0,0)$ and $f_y(0,0)$.
> 3. Check whether $f$ is differentiable at $(0,0)$.

The first two parts are trivial and I got $f_x(0,0)=f_y(0,0)=0$. My question is part 3.

My attempt:

Note that $f$ is differentiable at $(0,0)$ if $f_x(0,0)$ and $f_y(0,0)$ both exist and $$\lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)} \frac{f(x,y)-h(x,y)}{||(x,y)-(0,0)||}=0$$ where $h(x,y)=f(0,0)+f_x(0,0)(x-0)+f_y(0,0)(y-0)$. After calculation with polar coordinates, I get $$\begin{align}\lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)} \frac{f(x,y)-h(x,y)}{||(x,y)-(0,0)||}
&=\lim_{r \rightarrow 0} \frac{\cos^2\theta \sin (r\sin \theta)}{r}\\
&=\lim_{r \rightarrow 0} \frac{\cos^2\theta \sin \theta \sin (r\sin \theta)}{r\sin \theta}\\
&=\lim_{r \rightarrow 0} \cos^2\theta \sin \theta\end{align}$$ Note that the above does not converge and hence $f$ is not differentiable at $(0,0)$.

Is my answer correct? Do we have any other methods to tackle question 3? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @GitGud : What about now?

Comment: If no one answers the question in a few days, you'd good in answering it yourself.